# PHP Search bar for website

Tags: php, html

I was making a search bar where a user could find other users, but i keep getting 'could not search'. here is my code:

```
 <div class="widget widget_search">
              <h4 class="widget-title">Search</h4><!-- /.widget-title -->
              <div class="widget-details">
                <form action="blog.php" class="search-form" method="post">
                  <input type="text" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Search for.." required>
                  <button type="submit" name = "submit" value = "search" class="search-submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
              </div><!-- /.widget-details -->
            </div><!-- /.widget -->
            <?php print("$output");?>
```

and my php

```
<?php
mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');
      $output ='';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z&]#i", "", $searchq);
  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
  $output = 'There were no search results!';
}else{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $name = $row['username'];
    $dateofb = $row['dateofb'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $output .= '<div> '.$name.' '.$dateofb.'</div>';
  }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: check this output value $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z&]#i", "", $searchq);

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');
```

should be

```
$myMysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');
```

and then

```
$myMysqli->mysqli_query()
```

And please, use parameters for your input into the query :)

Comment: Thank you, but now I keep getting that my page is not working...(